# PL/SQL: Declaration variable on select within select for percentage

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, declaration, percentage

I am new to SQL and learnt mostly using YouTube, Google and some online tasks. I am trying to figure out how best perform a simple task to work out what percentage of 'goals' have been scored on one side of a soccer pitch. I am not sure if this is the best approach, but have tried to subquery and can't work out how to make that work with this either. Like I said, still new and keen to learn new method.

The following is the method I have been trying to use. By counting the total goals (excluding goals from the centre line), then in the second part dividing it by that number and multiplying by 100 to give me the percentage of that half.

```
DECLARE
        l_goal NUMBER(3);
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(y_axis) INTO l_goal
    FROM soccer_stats
    WHERE y_axis <> 0;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (SELECT ROUND(COUNT(y_axis)/||l_goal)
    FROM soccer_stats
    WHERE y_axis < 0);
END;
```

Below was my attempt at doing a subquery.

```
    SELECT COUNT(y_axis) FROM soccer_stats
    WHERE y_axis <> 0
    (SELECT ROUND(COUNT(y_axis)/6*100) FROM soccer_stats
    WHERE y_axis < 0)
                                ^-------- '6' was the goal number, but could find a way to automate.
```

If you could help me get my head around where I am going wrong, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple SQL query as below should be good enough,

```
select (yaxiscount/(yaxiscount + nonyaxiscount))*100 yaxispercentage,(nonyaxiscount/(yaxiscount + nonyaxiscount))*100  nonyaxispercentage
from 
(SELECT COUNT(y_axis) yaxiscount
    FROM soccer_stats
    WHERE y_axis >= 0),
    (SELECT COUNT(y_axis) nonyaxiscount
        FROM soccer_stats
        WHERE y_axis < 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I found it hard trying to find an easy to understand answer online, but this has made things much clearer for me.

Comment: Good to know it worked. If you could mark/upvote all answers that had resolved your issue that would definitely help all stackoverflow users.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the question.

```
DECLARE
    l_goal NUMBER(3);
    l_pct  NUMBER;
BEGIN
    -- populate L_GOAL variable
    SELECT COUNT(y_axis) 
      INTO l_goal
      FROM soccer_stats
      WHERE y_axis <> 0;

    -- now use it
    SELECT ROUND(COUNT(y_axis) / l_goal * 100)
      INTO l_pct
      FROM soccer_stats
      WHERE y_axis < 0;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('l_goal = ' || l_goal ||', l_pct = ' || l_pct);    
END;
```

Comment: Littlefoot, thank you for getting back to me on short notice. This works great thanks